Swiper products Carousel display half products
Good evening, I'm trying to make a carousel of products with Swiper and it shows  half products on the right and left. I want to not show half products. Here the link with the example of the result https://elkoso.lv/test.php and the code I use:
<?php 
// Απαιτείται WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');

// Προσθήκη του CSS και του JS για το Swiper
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />';
echo '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>';

// Προσθήκη του CSS για τα custom styles του καρουζέλ
echo '<style>
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* Αλλαγή σε auto για να προσαρμόζεται */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
   width: 343px!important;  /* Μειωμένο πλάτος για καλύτερη εμφάνιση */
    margin: 0 5px; /* Μειωμένο margin */
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Απόσταση από την εικόνα */
}

.product-info {
    background-color: #2f5d8c;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
}

.product-info h2 {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.product-info a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2f5d8c;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.product-info a.button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: #2f5d8c;
}

/* Κουμπιά πλοήγησης */
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
    color: #666;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.swiper-button-next:hover,
.swiper-button-prev:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Pagination */
.swiper-pagination {
    bottom: 5px;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    background: #999;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background: #2f5d8c;
}


/*Απόσταση των bullets απο το bottom*/
.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets, .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal, .swiper-pagination-custom, .swiper-pagination-fraction {
    bottom: var(--swiper-pagination-bottom, 25%);
    top: var(--swiper-pagination-top, auto);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>';

// Δημιουργία του καρουζέλ
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'μπεκ',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Λάβετε όλα τα προϊόντα
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="swiper">';
    echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper">';

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        global $product; // Απαιτείται για πρόσβαση στα προϊόντα WooCommerce

        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
        // Εμφάνιση εικόνας προϊόντος
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        // Εμφάνιση τίτλου προϊόντος
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
        // Εμφάνιση κουμπιού προσθήκης στο καλάθι
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()) . '" class="button add_to_cart_button">' . __('Προσθήκη στο καλάθι') . '</a>';
        echo '</div>'; // Κλείσιμο του product-info
        echo '</div>'; // Κλείσιμο του swiper-slide
    }

    echo '</div>'; // Κλείσιμο του swiper-wrapper

    // Προσθήκη των κουμπιών πλοήγησης
    echo '<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>';
    echo '<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>';

    // Προσθήκη pagination
    echo '<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>';

    echo '</div>'; // Κλείσιμο του swiper
}
wp_reset_postdata();

// Προσθήκη JavaScript για την ενεργοποίηση του Swiper
echo '<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    slidesPerView: 5, // Show 5 full slides
    spaceBetween: 5,
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: false, // Disable centered slides
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
</script>';
?>

I want to display the carousel give 5 products at desktop and laptop, 3 products at tables and one at mobiles, and don't show half products at left and at the right of the display.

So you're aiming for the "all or nothing" view of the products?

You should probably look into the breakpoints option, https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints
